# Как посчитать количество строк в проекте?

Tags: c++, clion

Как посчитать количество строк в проекте CLion??

Comment: Для `CLion` можно также использовать плагин [Statistic](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4509-statistic)

Answer (score 6):

Как вариант, программа `cloc` (от 'Count Lines Of Code').

На Линуксах ее можно найти в пакетных менеджерах. Для Windows - [здесь](https://sourceforge.net/projects/cloc/files/).

Она не привязана к Clion или C++, и считает строки во всех файлах в папке/архиве, разделяя их по языкам.

Пример работы ([отсюда](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/)):

```
prompt> cloc perl-5.10.0.tar.gz
    4076 text files.
    3883 unique files.                                          
    1521 files ignored.

http://cloc.sourceforge.net v 1.50  T=12.0 s (209.2 files/s, 70472.1 lines/s)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Language                     files          blank        comment           code
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Perl                          2052         110356         130018         292281
C                              135          18718          22862         140483
C/C++ Header                   147           7650          12093          44042
Bourne Shell                   116           3402           5789          36882
Lisp                             1            684           2242           7515
make                             7            498            473           2044
C++                             10            312            277           2000
XML                             26            231              0           1972
yacc                             2            128             97           1549
YAML                             2              2              0            489
DOS Batch                       11             85             50            322
HTML                             1             19              2             98
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SUM:                          2510         142085         173903         529677
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну или в баше, например:

```
[bipll@home libs]$ find . \( -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cpp' \) -exec cat '{}' \; | wc -l
13374
```

Не очень изящно, но действенно.